# PHP : How to get returned link when access a link

Tags: facebook, image, hyperlink, get

I have a problem and I hope you all will help me. I'm using Wordpress. In my country, facebook is banned. So I can't access my Facebook Profile Picture at :

Link A : http://graph.facebook.com/100001225080368/picture -> and facebook will return link B to browser :

Link B :  http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/161159_100001225080368_1270343183_q.jpg

I have an app on my blog. It will connect to facebook and get all data (status, picture, link, like...), and then, display on my blog. The problem is : text data can be displayed but profile picture can't be. That because the code to display profile picture is :

```
<img src="$fb_pic_id" />
```

$fb_pic_id in my php code will return Link A -> this link has facebook domain in it and in my country (facebook is banned), the browser can't display and the connect will be timeout after 30s by default.

But if I pass Link B to "src" attr, the profile picture will be displayed. But I cant hardcode this link in my php code beacause when I (and other users) change profile picture, Link B will not true.

So I want to ask if we can using PHP code to get the Link B that returned from Link A and after that, I will set LinkB to "src" attr to display the newest facebook profile picture ID.

Thanks and I hope you will help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is using HTTP redirection using `Location` header so it's pretty simple to get final URL of an image:

```
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/100001225080368/picture';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$headers = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($code == 302) {
  preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $headers, $matches);
  // NOTE: this will contain URL from `*.fbcdn.net`
  $directURL = trim(array_pop($matches));
} else {
  // NOTE: Previous code wasn't redirect by Facebook to original image
  // Do some fallback...
}
```